# SQLite Sum and CASE statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table

```
----------------------
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
----------------------
| 1    |text1 | 1    |
----------------------
|  98  |text2 | 2    |
----------------------
| 2    |text3 | 1    |
----------------------
| 98   |text4 | 3    |
----------------------
```

I need to get a `Sum` of `Col3` where `Col1 = 98` and `Sum` of `Col3` where `Col1 <> 98`. The desired result would be 5 and 2.

```
-------------------------------
| aShort (=98) | aLong (<>98) |
-------------------------------
|     5        |      2       |
-------------------------------
```

My `SQL query` looks like that:

```
'SELECT sum(case when Col1 = 98 then Col3 else 0 end) as aShort, ' +
  'sum(case when Col1 <> 98 then Col3 else 0 end) as aLong '...
```

And the result that i get is 0 and 7.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The code you posted is correct: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4oMSAv2xM35ABcjKd8Vhzu/0 So the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose data type of `Col1` is not integer or numeric but of string type such as `text` or `varchar`, and seems values contain some whitespaces in them. I strongly recommend to hold a numeric value within a numeric type of column, but in the current case you need to cast as integer in order to get such a result as desired using the query below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(Col1 AS INT)  = 98 THEN Col3 ELSE 0 END) AS aShort, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(Col1 AS INT) <> 98 THEN Col3 ELSE 0 END) AS aLong
  FROM tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7320880873cd03207d2cb8aa5f99b5d3)</kbd>

Comment: Nice catch for the  whitespaces. In the 2nd row of the sample data it is clear that there must be a leading space.

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan thank you for the answer, but the problem was not the white spaces, or incorrect data type. The external code that is saved in `Col1` was changed from 98 to 99 and i had no chance to check the current table.